# Bootstrap forms changing size when they are validated

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio, validation, html-helper

I'm new with frontend, so I'm starting with bootstrap 'to make my life easier (or not), but I'm having some trouble adjusting forms

When validating those fields, the forms change the size, how would can i standardize those sizes?

Already tried to change the css of the form-control, but without success

Here some images from the formns

[Forms Without validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jttav.png)

Here the forms when they are validated

[Forms with validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0qfH.png)

CODE:

```
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Barco.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })

        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Barco.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Barco.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Barco.SapId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Barco.SapId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Barco.SapId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Barco.CapacidadeAgua, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Barco.CapacidadeAgua, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Barco.CapacidadeAgua, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Barco.CapacidadeOleo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Barco.CapacidadeOleo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Barco.CapacidadeOleo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Barco.Velocidade, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Barco.Velocidade, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control " } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Barco.Velocidade, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Barco.Setor, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Barco.Setor, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Barco.Setor, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Barco.Setor, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Barco.Setor, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Barco.Setor, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>



    @Html.Partial("_ClasseBarco")

    <div class="form-group">

        <div class=" col-md-12 col-md-12">

            <input type="submit" value="Adicionar" class="btn btn-success" />
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Barcos")" class="btn btn-default">Voltar </a>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just wrap `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` tags inside a `<div>` to get full control on the style:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Barco.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    <div class="validation-style">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Barco.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

And create your own styles in your `css` file:

```
.validation-style {
    font-size: 14px !important;
    // color, font-weight, margin-top, padding-left, etc. :-)
}
```

If you don't like `text-danger`, just remove it and define all your styles inside `validation-style`.

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Barco.Nome, "", new { @class = "" })
```